# Отправка нескольких картинок в виде base64

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пытаюсь сделать на canvas-e uploader картинок.
Условия таковы:

1. Должно быть три кнопки выбора картинки (Browse) (Макс. 3 фото).
2. При выборе картинки генерируется base64 и подставляется в скрытый input.
3. После чего при отправки формы отсылаем base64 на обработку скрипту.

Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю как правильно реализовать.

Код формы:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
    <label for="fileToUpload">Select Files to Upload</label>
    <input type="text" name="photo[]" id="hiddenInput0" value="">
    <input type="text" name="photo[]" id="hiddenInput1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="photo[]" id="hiddenInput2" value="">
    <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload0" accept="image/*">
    <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload1" accept='image/*'>
    <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload2" accept='image/*' />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Скрипт, который получает значения с `#filesToUpload0`:

```js
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('filesToUpload' + 0).onchange = function() {
        var files = document.getElementById('filesToUpload' + 0).files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            resizeAndUpload(files[i], i);
        }
    };
}
else {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
```

Дело в том, что я не могу отправить функции значения `#filesToUpload1` и `#filesToUpload2`.

Т.е. мне нужно отправить три значения, с каждого *Browse* вот этому скрипту, который получает их и подставляет в скрытый input base64 картинки.

```
function resizeAndUpload(file, num) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        var tempImg = new Image();
        tempImg.src = reader.result;
        tempImg.onload = function() {
            var MAX_WIDTH = 640;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 480;
            var tempW = tempImg.width;
            var tempH = tempImg.height;
            if (tempW > tempH) {
                if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
                    tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
                    tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = tempW;
            canvas.height = tempH;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); 
            $("#hiddenInput" + num).val(dataURL); //тут вставляем значение в скрытый input
        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Понимаю что тут натворил, но я пытаюсь сделать как можно проще и правильней. А не подставлять костыли, а потом "то работает, то нет".

Идея состоит в том, что пользователь заходит на страницу, заполняет форму.
В конце формы он прикрепляет максимум 3 картинки и отправляет форму на обработку PHP скрипту.

Хочу использовать canvas, потому что фотографии от 2 до 3 мегабайтов, а он как раз их уменьшает на стороне клиента, что мне и требуется.

Также хочу спросить: как в плане безопасности работает этот код?
Нужны ли какие-либо проверки в PHP обработке, чтобы не попало чего лишнего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `.files` у `#filesToUpload0` находится только один файл, выбранный именно в этом `<input>`-е. Вешать обработчик события `change` нужно на все 3 `<input>`-a:

```js
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    $(".file").on("change", function() {
        if (this.files.length != 0) {
            resizeAndUpload(this.files[0], $(this).data("id"));
        }
    });
}
else {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}

function resizeAndUpload(file, num) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        var tempImg = new Image();
        tempImg.src = reader.result;
        tempImg.onload = function() {
            var MAX_WIDTH = 640;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 480;
            var tempW = tempImg.width;
            var tempH = tempImg.height;
            if (tempW > tempH) {
                if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
                    tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
                    tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = tempW;
            canvas.height = tempH;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            $("#hiddenInput" + num).val(dataURL);
        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
    <label for="fileToUpload">Select Files to Upload</label>
    <input type="text" name="photo[]" id="hiddenInput0" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="photo[]" id="hiddenInput1" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="photo[]" id="hiddenInput2" value="" />
    <input type="file" class="file" data-id="0" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="file" class="file" data-id="1" accept='image/*' />
    <input type="file" class="file" data-id="2" accept='image/*' />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Рефакторингом функции `resizeAndUpload` я не занимался.
У `<input type="file">` я убрал `name`, чтобы сами картинки на сервер не уходили. Если вам нужны и сами картинки, и их копия в base64, то `name` нужно вернуть.

На стороне сервера нужно обязательно проверять приходящие данные. Проверки на клиенте (браузере в данном случае) делаются для удобства клиента. Проверки на сервере - для безопасности.

Comment: Спасибо ! А вобще я правильно делаю ? то что скрываю base64 в инпутах а потом их на сервер отправляю вместе с формой ? По поводу безопасности я нашел пару методов как валидировать base64 на обнаружение картинки. Правда не знаю какой способ лучше, но все же придется поискать более простой и надежный способ валидации на стороне сервера.

Comment: @StackOverFollow "правильно" - понятие относительное. Если в плане работоспособности, то должно работать. В плане оптимизации объёма передаваемых данных - не помню как по умолчанию передаются файлы в HTTP. Если в бинарном виде, то base64 проиграет в этом плане. Скрытые `<input>`-ы - это вроде как не костыльность, особенно если форма отправляется не Ajax-ом.

Comment: Ну под словом правильно я имел ввиду, не нарушает ли это саму логику работы - на всех уровнях - как понял нет, и это хорошо. Просто мне нужен был простейший код, так как в сети, есть много вариантов, но там награможденно много лишнего. Большое спасибо за помощь !